# duda BDOO Failed JUnit.framework

Tags: java

Hola me sale el siguiente error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at TestGestors.provaIncrementarPreuDistribuidor1(TestGestors.java:189)
```

y este otro

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at TestGestors.provaIncrementarPreu(TestGestors.java:183)
```

no sé que significa ni entiendo como evitarlo.

pongo las partes de código que dan el Show Failed:

Linea 189

```
 @Test
    public void provaIncrementarPreuDistribuidor1() throws GestorException{
        gestorArticleExtern.incrementarPreu(1, 70);
        assertTrue(comparaLlistesArticles(gestorArticle.obtenirArticles(),totsIncrementatsEl70pcDist1));
    }  



 public void incrementarPreu(int codiDistribuidor, float percentantge) {
        //TODO completar el metode

        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Article a");
          List<Article> articles = q.getResultList();
          for (Article a : articles) {
    a.setPreu(a.getPreu() * percentantge);
    em.merge(a);
}

    }
```

linea 183

```
 public void provaIncrementarPreu() throws GestorException{
        gestorArticle.incrementarPreu(50);
        assertTrue(comparaLlistesArticles(gestorArticle.obtenirArticles(),totsIncrementatsEl50pc));
    } 

 public void incrementarPreu(float percentantge) {
        //TODO completar el metode
        Query ap = em.createNamedQuery("Article.aumentapreu");
        ap.setParameter("quantitat", percentantge);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        ap.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();



    }
```

me falta algo?

Comment: Es una clase de test? AssertTrue pareceria estar buscando que la funcion devuelva true.. pero devuelve void.

Comment: si es decir de cada código que he puesto la parte de public void provaIncrementar y provaDistribuidor1 son de dentro del test

Comment: pero tu test, tiene que testear algo.. si el metodo devuelve void, que esta testeando?

Comment: es decir en cada error he puesto la parte del test que falla y debajo el metodo que esta testeando.

Comment: Pero assert true verifica si se cumple una condicion (true o false), si tu metodo devuelve void, que esperas que verifique? Lo que le falta a tu test, es que queres testear..

Comment: el test no puedo cambiarlo. Pero si los métodos  public void incrementarPreu(float percentantge) y  public void incrementarPreu(int codiDistribuidor, float percentantge). Que lo que tengo que conseguir es un augmento de los codigos de distribuidor.

Comment: ok.. a ver.. tratemos de que este toda la info en la pregunta. Debes agregar, que es lo que queres testear, contra que lo queres testear, y la funcion que compara (para ver como compara, ya que esa es la que hace el test).